# Search Filter space not recognized

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am passing in a search filter with a category that has a space in it. It returns the correct result if there is no space.

So, if `Person2` is passed as `Person 2` below then it gives the wrong result:

```
string filter =
    String.Format("\"category <> 'Person' AND category <> 'Person2', subject: testsubject\"");

List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("$search", filter)
};

var messages = graphClient.Me
    .MailFolders
    .Inbox
    .Messages
    .Request(options)
    .Select("id, Categories, Subject")
    .Top(500)
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

Comment: I am thinking this may be due to the fact it can only fuzzy match..

Answer (score 1):

The `$search` query parameter using [Keyword Query Language (KQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference). According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#constructing-free-text-queries-using-kql), phrases need to be double-quoted:

> Free text KQL queries are case-insensitive but the operators must be in uppercase. You can construct KQL queries by using one or more of the following as free-text expressions:
>
> - A **word** (includes one or more characters without spaces or punctuation)
> - A **phrase** (includes two or more words together, separated by spaces; however, the words must be enclosed in double quotation marks)

Try enclosing your category strings in double-quotes:

```
string filter = "\"category <> \\\"Person\\\" AND category <> \\\"Person 2\\\", subject: testsubject\""
```

Note that in order to send the quote through the API it needs to be escaped (`\"`). In order to have C# include the escaped sequence in the string, the escape character must ALSO be escaped (`\\` + `\"`).  This is why you end up with the odd-looking triple slash (`\\\"`).

Comment: Hi Marc - I have tried the above, but when i search for results with a search filter as category <> "Person" , it returns the matches for "Person" and "Person 2", even with the quotations.

Comment: That is because both "Person" and "Person 2" contain the word "Person". Quotations tell it to require multiple words as a single phrase (each word is there and in a specific order). The quotes ensure that "Person 2" doesn't pick up "Person", not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, so If I wanted to pass a filter:
Is this valid? It seems if i use \\\" in category, then it doesnt like it in subject..
("\"category <> \\\"Person\\\" AND category <> \\\"Person2\\\", subject: \\\"testsubject 1\\\"\"");

Comment: Marc , I am struggling to find the answer but why are we including an escape string so instead of \\\”, why don’t we do \” inside the string?